Should questions about Logic be off-topic
If we are trying to reason, then Logic is required, it is not up for debate. When I see questions about Logic, I think that they are actually math questions and should be covered on a math question site. Logic is not part of reasoning, it underlies reasoning. You can't discuss how logic should work, just like you can't argue for different kinds of arithmetic at the grocery store checkout counter, it is too late there.
Can we redirect questions about Logic to a math site?

Don't show up at the construction site wondering how to weld or mix concrete.

They might belong to maths, but there is no bad intention, no flooding of this site, no long discussions and flames.

@tkruse ok, no holy wars over logic here I guess, but if I see another question about LEM, or trying to prove once and for all that A = A, I'm gonna be miffed.

I ask because to me, philosophy is a place to solve higher level problems, and we don't get very far if we haven't agreed on seemingly even what constitutes a question or an answer. Can someone show me to the site where the basics are already understood and agreed on and we can work on actual problems without being run over by wayward public transportation? (trolleys, ha ha)

"Don't show up at the construction site wondering how to weld or mix concrete." @ScottRowe I never do. First time I did, I found myself in a slump! ; ) BTW, you could set your filters to identify common logic tags, and just avoid them.

@ScottRowe I get excited when I see a logic question. If you don't like them, just don't read them! Why do you have to suppress questions that you're not interested in?

@MissUnderstands it isn't so much that I'm not interested in them, it just feels like when people get picky about wording and syntax. Like, pointless debate about things that I thought we had already agreed on just to get in the door. I mean, if you go out to dinner and people argue over what kind of dress clothes are ok instead of talking about the food or the weather or something, it's annoying, right? We're already here, as Kesha said. Your answer about relativity or whatever was a great visualization for me. I avoid math, but when someone helps me see what the equation means it helps.

@ScottRowe > . Your answer about relativity or whatever was a great visualization for me == [mandatory curtsie, brief]  == >when people get picky about wording and syntax. Like, pointless debate about things that I thought we had already agreed == Apparently some people disagree. Again, why can't you just not read the logic questions? Some people are interested in syntax. I am, and it's how Chomsky paid the rent.

I'm just impatient, I guess.

@ScottRowe If you live in a "green" state, I got just the thang for you: https://www.bluescentric.com/images/product/large/2442_1_.jpg

Saw Timothy Leary speak when I was in college. He seemed pretty scatterbrained. "Reality is for people who can't handle drugs."

I disagree.

Logic was invented by philosophers. Historically, logic has largely been developed by philosophers, or at the least, people who had strong philosophical motivations. Even today, philosophers are pushing the boundaries of logic.

Logic is one of the core disciplines of philosophy. It is an important component of critical thinking. It is neither feasible nor desirable to remove logic from philosophy. Many philosophers do technical work in the area of logic.

Sometimes we get questions that are purely technical, such as asking how to construct a formal proof. Questions that are concerned only with pushing symbols around within a given formal system might be better off on a math site, but it's hardly a major problem. We are not inundated with those questions and it is not a big deal if some subject matter is handled on more than one site.

Questions about logic are frequently expressed in natural language. This is a different matter, because often the hard part is understanding how to translate between the natural and the formal. Also it may involve using one or more extensions to basic logic, such as modal logics, or temporal logic, or conditional logics, etc. It may also involve knowledge of related areas such as implicatures, speech acts, linguistics, etc. Mathematicians do not usually have any particular expertise in that.

Expanding on that thought, and with the risk of being more controversial... most mathematicians don't know much about logic anyway. I should qualify that I'm using 'mathematician' here in a broad sense to mean someone with a bachelor's degree in mathematics. This means they did an undergraduate level course in logic and learned first order classical logic. Maybe if they were lucky they were introduced to intuitionistic logic, second order logic and perhaps even some modal logic. Probably not. By my standards, that counts as not much. Mathematicians typically only study the fragment of logic that they need for their own work. Which is first order classical logic, maybe second order and maybe intuitionistic logic for constructive mathematics. Logic is a huge subject and while it overlaps with mathematics, it is much bigger than the fragment that mathematicians choose to study. There are of course plenty of mathematicians who have done graduate level work in logic and know a lot more than most. But even then, they mostly study the areas of logic that are directly applicable to mathematics. Mathematics is unimodal: it is modally flat. A mathematical proposition is true or it's false. Or if you like to think of mathematical propositions as necessary, then it's necessarily true or necessarily false. The real world is full of modalities and intentionalities. Some propositions are contingently true, some are necessarily true, some ought to be true, some might have been true but aren't, some I believe to be true, some I know to be true, some might be true for all I know, some I wish were true, some I promise to make true, etc. Developing logics that handle diverse semantics and modalities is something that mathematicians are not usually interested in because it is not relevant to their own ends. Enter philosophers. Most of the work that has been done in these areas has been done by philosophers. If you ask questions about this stuff on math stackexchange they'll close them and tell you to ask them here.

I disagree with your claim that "you can't discuss how logic should work". You seem to have a platonistic view of logic. For myself, I regard logics as tools that we create and use for solving problems. There are lots of logics and it makes excellent sense to enquire how they work and why we should use one for a particular purpose. There is a large literature concerned with such subjects.



As a mathematician, I strongly agree with this answer's descriptions of the limitations of mathematicians when it comes to logic.

I've got some problems with that. If we are talking about mathematical (or computational)  logics like what fully evolved in the 1930-1940s onwards, your reasoning seems valid to me. We should not try to process questions that are purely technical and completely disconnected from the syntactic rules and fluidity of natural language.
Conversely, Moore, Russel, Frege, Carnapp, Wittgenstein, and their forefathers up to the old Greeks (and Egyptians, Persians, Indians and so on no less), all who led to the famous quote "The structure of our language is the structure of our world", are part of and integral to the history and present of philosophy.
Another aspect of this is that propositional logics are standard content of any good philosophy undergrad.
Thus, my take would be that, indeed, mathematical logic and all the tantrums revolving around it can barely be considered on-topic if not explicitly linked to an explicitly philosophical problem, while everything that broadly keeps logics in contact with natural language is at the heart of philosophy as one of the structural and reflective cornerstones.

It seems like you are taking an explicit position that philosophy must be "in contact with natural language." Many philosophers, such as the positivists, wouldn't agree with that. I take it as the ultimate goal of philosophy to express and understand certain natural language concepts mathematically. To really understand something to the maximum degree, it is necessary (though not sufficient) to write a rigorous formula for it. Natural language is full of vagueness, making it easy to hide subtly invalid reasoning.

@causative I would not agree with your take on a positivist stance. Carnapp's scientific language was bound to fail because mathematical structure does not translate to meaning the way he originally thought. This was his great insight and both the epitome and death of positivism. In other words: Yes, the point is exactly that it is a philosophical, not a mathematical, insight that meaning cannot be fully captured by "rigorous formulae".

@causative "You got your chocolate in my peanut butter!..." My goal as a computer programmer is to pave ten lanes of I-696 between natural language and the structure of programs and especially, data. Maybe I'm the only one who drives on it, because everyone stays on the East side, but it is definitely there. SQL data structure is my personal holy grail, but, most people are not amused. So, there you go: it's both. I strive to know when to bring something up, and when to not. If someone says, the freeway is going around this church, I go around it, usually discovering something new.

@ScottRowe There's the saying that you don't really understand something until you can teach it to your grandma. I like to say that you don't really understand something until you can teach it to a computer!

@PhilipKlöcking Regardless, it is not universally accepted that positivism is "dead" or that meaning cannot be captured by rigorous formulae. Right or wrong, that's your personal view. Self-described "analytic" philosophers are actually a majority in the philpapers poll. I think we should be accepting of philosophical views from any perspective, including perspectives that differ from our own; there should not be an enforced canon of "correct" philosophy here with other viewpoints censored, especially if those viewpoints have significant representation among academic philosophers.

@causative fair enough. My grandma died a couple years before I sat down at a teletype in 8th grade, but I've definitely taught computers, and especially SQL, a thing or two. I've written crosstab queries that are almost a page long. Used to keep a fist-sized rock on my desk and wave it menacingly at the screen. Teaching humans to program is, arguably, harder. I TA'ed an into programming course for non-majors in 1987. Some people got it, some could manage after a while, some never got it. Interesting idea for a research project, eh? The camel has 2 humps and all...

Sorry if it seems that I was arguing for censorship - unintended consequence. I was just thinking that this kind of question is not really what this site is for, and is better handled somewhere else. It often feels like while we try to set down some arguments other people are trying to saw off the limb we are all sitting on.

@causative Sorry for an acerbic comment. See my answer

"Improvement makes straight roads, but the crooked roads, without improvements, are roads of genius." -- William Blake

A strong argument for why things like "truth" or "meaning" or "consciousness" should in principle be formalizable, is that the mind is nothing more than a machine, and any machine may be described and modeled mathematically. As justification, the mind corresponds to and is wholly dependent on the brain, which certainly can be described and modeled mathematically. Since "meaning" and "consciousness" are nothing more than attributes of this machine, they also should, in principle, be analyzable with mathematics and logic.

To dispute that, I think you have to hold either that the brain can't be modeled mathematically, that the mind is not wholly dependent on the brain, that meaning and consciousness are not properties of the mind, or that a machine that can be modeled mathematically can have properties that can't be modeled mathematically, all of which are fairly controversial positions.

@caustive I understand that those are all reasoned arguments, but I'm not here to argue. It is sort of a waking nightmare for humanity that we might soon create our betters, and then it might not be so good for us. There are a lot more chickens now than 10,000 years ago, and a lot fewer buffalo, wolves, passenger pigeons, blue whales... And the chickens don't have such good lives, I see truckloads of them on my way to work. Prove mathematically that AI will do a better job with the planet than we did and I'll listen. If they're superior, the Game Theory findings on cooperation won't help.

Otherwise, I think research into how to formalize and program Ethics / morality is probably the most important thing in the universe for humanity to be doing, right now. Any disagreement?

@ScottRowe I would disagree. I think ethics and morality are worth nothing without practice. It is nice to have some formal code but the most important thing is, for me anyways, that people stop debating, formalising, or whatever about basic rights (and when to dispose of them) but simply act decently without any second thought.

@PhilipKlöcking right, but in the meantime, I'm happy that we have laws. And, my last speeding ticket was, 1986 I think. Long ago I also tee-boned an ambulance and didn't even need to go to court: he crossed against the light without his siren on and we couldn't see each other. Yes.

As someone with a heavy interest in the linguistical notion of formal semantics, I'm going to pile on.
Reasoning underlies logic, not vice versa. Logic, which is a formal science, is an abstraction of human reasoning, which is largely a natural science. Formal systems to describe logic are an abstraction of reasoning on my view, which is to say, that doxastic processes are broader and more fundamental than epistemological processes. What you see as "mathematics" is really an entirely different branch of formal systems distinct from mathematical systems even if the methodology and the symbols are superficially related. This has everything to do with the idea that logical primitives and processes are of a fundamentally distinct character than mathematical primitives and processes psychologically. And ultimately, the formal systems of logic, particularly the non-classical logics are demonstrative of how we reason differently in different contexts.
This distinction in processing between of mathematics and logic is reflected in computer science in the study of AI where some algorithms are highly mathematical (ordering a set of elements for instance which requires applying ordinal structure), and some algorithms are highly logical (moving through a search space in natural language to look for signs of conceptual contrast expressed with logical operators in adversative linguistic constructions). AI tends to be characterized more as the latter particularly with the intent of automating human goal-based thinking relying on logic as a stand in for human reason. Whereas mathematical reasoning deals in order, sets, and statistics,  logical reasoning deals with negation, contraposition, implication, and so on. These are absolutely distinct concepts, disciplines, and formal systems.
So, certainly, at first glance, one might look at the symbols that represent the variables and operations of logic and mathematics (particularly when doing mathematical logic) and see them as essentially the same, but they are not, and it took philosophers 2,500 years to combine them in a meaningful way. Even now, mathematicians and logicians demonstrate a very different conceptual expertise. The computer scientist Erik Larson in his book The Myth of Artificial Intelligence has a chapter where he essentially defines the goal of human-level AI as akin to building systems that not only can do deductive and inductive computations, but abductive ones as well, and if this is taken as a reflection of a characterization of human reasoning, then it is not for a shortage of mathematical knowledge that AI fails to meet our expectations of human-level intelligence, but a shortage of logical knowledge. And it is that distinction that Philosophy SE honors when various contributors such as Bumble share knowledge of logics that lie outside any mathematical training I've ever had.

Right. It seems that I find no end of reasons to become even more humbled by the brilliant people here and elsewhere around me. I guess my goals are very different from the people posting in Phil SE. I must be the one "marching the wrong way."

There is no right way, Scott. : )

@ScottRowe >  I find no end of reasons to become even more humbled by the brilliant people here == [curtsies]

There is a great deal of presentism in this question as often happens on this site in general.
[Note: I'm referring to the historical not philosophical use of the term]
Bumble has a splendid recent answer on this which I recommend as a point of departure:. It starts

Historically, logic and mathematics were separate disciplines and had little to do with one another

To which I would add the complement:

Logic from its very inception (at least in the western world) starts with Aristotle and is therefore intimately tied to philosophy.

So is there not some merit in your wish?
Yes — Very much so!
So logic in its historical aspect starts 2½ millennia ago with Aristotle.
But formal logic starts with Boole, Frege et al no earlier than the 19th century.  And then pushed to new heights by the foundationalists Russell etc culminating in Gödel. And I add (because you're a computer guy) And Turing.
So for 2 thousand years formalization was not a thing (apart from the occasional outliers like Leibniz and Ramus)
So then why did this formalization mania?
This is related to the crisis in the foundations of math end 19th century.
So from end 19th century to the 1930s there was a hope to resolve this.
Gödel and Turing smashed this hope by reifying incompleteness, undecidability.  And I may add Tarski — undefinability.
In spelling out undecidability, Turing had to define a grand sounding thing then called universality.  But we now call programmability. And thanks to which we got the computer!
In short formalization has lost its way and its raison d'être after these guys. And persists only by virtue of a strongly ahistorical, presentist view of the field.  But also the quest for formalization had some profound world-altering effects.
This brings me to:
An Apologetic retraction
Causative above made a comment: I take it as the ultimate goal of philosophy to express and understand certain natural language concepts mathematically.
Which annoyed me to retort:

»The ULTIMATE goal of philosophy is to express and understand certain natural language concepts mathematically.« The ludicrous presentism that permeates so much discussion out here. I happen to belong the group — evidently minority — that considers philosophy to start with Socrates (or Thales) and not Boole Frege and Russell. If Socrates would not understand what you're onto you evidently take it that you have transcended his wisdom. I take it youre nitpicking. Or simply wrong. Formalization is engineering not philosophy

I guess I was unnecessarily acerbic here.
My justification (excuse) is that if we have philosopher hats on: Causative is in the formalist camp and I am in the anti-formalist camp. And we can have a debate. And it should be healthy and civil.
When we switch from philosopher to user/mod hats there is a general expectation that mods keep their preferences to the side when they take (moderating) actions.
I should have made clear I was speaking (as) to a mod not in philosopher mode.
Perhaps my deeper annoyance is with people who make it a point to remove the logic tag from questions that are on logic-but-not-formal-logic.
In the light of the above, I'd like to emphasize that this (nonformal) logic has a 20 times older provenance than formal logic — 2 millennia vs 1 century.
Short Answer

Logic cannot meaningfully be excised out of philosophy.
Over-emphasis on formal logic is unhealthy. And passé.
Even more so the equation logic = formal logic.


Maybe everyone should always keep all of their preferences to the side?

@ScottRowe Im not sure what that even means. Seriously. Are tea and coffee the same to you? Even enlightened masters (lets assume we agree that that is an authentic ontic category) have their preferences ranging from food to outlook to favorite format of deity

It's fine to like things, but agreement will seldom include all of my wants.

@ScottRowe Again I dont know what you are saying. People have a worldview. Worldviews can (often) clash. I recently enumerated some. Do you want to make the case that these clashes are incidental not fundamental? That can be an interesting and deep separate question.  But you can hardly wish away the clash

"Greed for views tends not to edification." -- the Buddha - Can we get past all this personal stuff? There's like, important things going on.

@ScottRowe I guess we would find agreement here. See — personal note. However do note that Buddha is kinda, sorta fringe out here. For better or worse. As I sometimes say (sorry for repeating): I dont like war. But the stocks of the arms manufacturers keep rising

"The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good [people] to do nothing." Are we the good people?

"The arrogance of reason has separated us from that love." Let's get the arrogance out of reason, it should be like a sidewalk under our feet.

@ScottRowe Please permit an Oriental to answer a Christian: Comment 1 (good-evil): Ans: Problems can be solved, resolved, dissolved or transcended. Latters better than formers. Comment 2: Arjuna: O Krishna! Be my master! Own me! And own the responsibility for my onerous actions. Or be my guru. Teach me. And let me act under the sun of full wisdom!  Krishna: The first choice is called bhakti. The second is jnana. And I'm going to take you on a wild romp through 18 chapters of philosophiland. When you swoon giddy you'll see the answer in your dream paraphrased of course

I guess we're not the good people then. Maybe we don't need to worry about the triumph of evil. Arjuna doesn't need to fight.
